# Add pip to current version of python

Tags: python, pip

my current version of python is 3.7, I was installed python-pip3 but not installed for the current version of my python but version 3.6, how can I set pip to a default version

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 18.1 from /home/gray/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to PyPy and follow the install instructions from there.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

But pip 3.7 may already be installed. Try

pip3.7 —version